# Get the text outside a DIV element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to access a page and get the value from this page.

**First I don't have access to this page so I can't do any modification on the code, that's the problem because it doesn't look coded properly.**

Please find an example (index.html) of the page (source)

I access this page with an ajax get method.

```
<div id="box" style="background-color:#000000; margin:0px;">
    <b>
        <big>
            <span style="color:#00BB77;">Tue, 02-08-2016</span>
        </big>
    </b>
</div>
MobApp iOS.A in C04
<br>
    09:00 am-11:00 am
<br>
<b>
    <big></big>
</b>
<br>
    MobApp Andr .A in C12
<br>
    01:30 pm-03:30 pm
<br>
<b>
    <big></big>
</b>
<br>
<div id="box" style="background-color:#000000; margin:0px;">
    <b>
        <big>
            <span style="color:#00BB77;">Wed, 03-08-2016</span>
        </big>
    </b>
</div>
    Adv. Studio 1.A in C11
<br>
    01:30 pm-03:30 pm
<br>
<b>
    <big></big>
</b>
<br>
<div id="box" style="background-color:#000000; margin:0px;">
    .....etc....
```

I already wrote a sample of a code to get the value inside the span (the date) with:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.thewebsite.com/index.html',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(res) {
      var data = $.parseHTML(res);
      $(data).find('#box').each(function() {
          alert($(this).find('span').html());
      });
   }
 });
```

And it works I get : 
Tue, 02-08-2016
Wed, 03-08-2016 etc...

I would like now to get what's after the `</div>` and the `<br>` (The subject) and the (time)

As you can see sometimes it can be only one subject per day or more.

I know it would have been much easier if everything would have been inside proper div element but they coded their website long time ago and they won't change that..

I tried to get some of the value with next() or nextSibling.nodeValue() but without success.

So thanks in advance for a tip or a solution.

Cheers

Comment: get the divs, then get the next sibling node, then the text you want is that nodes first sibling (not sibling node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with javascript child node with below way:

```
 var children= (document.getElementById("box")).childNodes;
 var i=-1,length=children.length;
 while(++i <  length){
  //chidrent text node will also come
 console.log(children[i]);

 }
```

Comment: The thing is I access the page from a remove server so everything is stored inside the data variable, so if I execute this script on my page it won't find anything.

Comment: do one thing then create a hidden div and store your ajax data there .otherwise  you will be not able to access with variable

Comment: Just tried, but I can only get what's inside the div id="box" and the data I want it's after the closing div not inside unfortunately. I try to get: 
MobApp iOS.A in C04 
09:00 am-11:00 am etc...

Comment: Finally got it right  Actually I checked the code source and I found another div which start at the beginning and end at the end, so I used this div id with your method and got the job done  I trimmed each result as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$(data).find('#box') will return only first element with ID box because ID selectors are unique. So if you want to access all the elements with ID box use a class selector instead.

For eg: Use class="box"
    `<div class="box" style="background-color:#000000; margin:0px;">`

Then

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.thewebsite.com/index.html',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(res) {
    var data = $.parseHTML(res);
    $(data).find('.box').each(function() {
      var children = this.childNodes,
        i = -1,
        length = children.length;

      while (++i < length) {
      console.log(children[i]); // This will give you each child nodes of div with class box. You can extract the HTML contents of these child nodes here.
    }
});
```